# Using GET Query Strings with Expressionengine and Structure

Tags: query-string, structure, expressionengine

I am trying to set up pagination on one of my EE Structure pages and the GET query string results in a 404 error. I think it has something to do with my .htaccess file but I cant figure it out. Here is my .htaccess file, I'm using the exclude method for removing the index.php from the URL,

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(images|system|themes|modules|scripts|uploads|css|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|index\.php|sitemap\.php|sitemap\.xml) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

So if I add some simple query like,

```
/account/?page=2
```

I get a 404 error...

Thanks for any help you guys can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out, not the most elegant option because it needs to be done for every page that you require query strings for...

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/account/$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?/account/index/&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

So this means you can use,

```
/account/?page=2
```

And then grab the GET query normally using PHP.

Thanks for your contributions guys.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's trying to find a template named "?page=2" and doesn't so it throws the 404 error.

Try using the index.php filename in the URL: /account/index.php?page=2.

Or, what I do is make the URL variables segments and use {segment_#} to parse them. So, /account/page2/ and then use {segment_2} in your template to get that variable.

Comment: Hi Chego, your first option results in a 404 error and the second seems to print the content of every page of my website! I also tried doing something like /account/2/ however that just seems to select the entry with the ID 2.

Answer (score 0):

**Where are your GET query strings being generated from?** Your [method of removing index.php from the URL](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/general/remove_index.php.html) will not have any effect on what the generated `{pagination_links}` will be.

ExpressionEngine's [paginations links](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/pagination_page.html) simply add a `/P5`, `/P10` or `/P15` [URL segment variable](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/url_segments.html) to the end of the current page's URL:

For example, given the following code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="site" dynamic="off" limit="5" paginate="bottom"}
    <p><a href="{title_permalink=structure/template}">{title}</a></p>

    {paginate}
        <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
    {/paginate}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The HTML output by ExpressionEngine for pagination links will be:

```
<p>
    Page 1 of 3 pages <strong>1</strong>
    <a href="/structure/template/P5">2</a>
    <a href="/structure/template/P10">3</a>
    <a href="/structure/template/P5">&gt;</a>
</p>
```

You'll notice the pagination links don't use any GET or POST query string parameters and instead use a URL segment variable of **P5**, **P10**, **P15**, and so on *(where P# is a multiple of the [limit parameter](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/parameters.html#par_limit) and the current index of the paginated result set)*.